# Multiple jQuery sliders moving each div on same page, any way to simplify code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, simplify

I have a page that has multiple sliders (from http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-jquery-slider-to-scroll-a-div) and since each of them are different divs I just duplicated the code and changed it to unique classes, which bring this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slider1").slider({
    animate: true,
    handle: ".handle1",
    change: handleSliderChange1,
    slide: handleSliderSlide1
  });

  $(".slider2").slider({
    animate: true,
    handle: ".handle2",
    change: handleSliderChange2,
    slide: handleSliderSlide2
  });

  $(".slider3").slider({
    animate: true,
    handle: ".handle3",
    change: handleSliderChange3,
    slide: handleSliderSlide3
  });

});

function handleSliderChange1(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $(".gal1").attr("scrollWidth") - $(".gal1").width();
  $(".gal1").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);
}

function handleSliderSlide1(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $(".gal1").attr("scrollWidth") - $(".gal1").width();
  $(".gal1").attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
}



function handleSliderChange2(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $(".gal2").attr("scrollWidth") - $(".gal2").width();
  $(".gal2").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);
}

function handleSliderSlide2(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $(".gal2").attr("scrollWidth") - $(".gal2").width();
  $(".gal2").attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
}


function handleSliderChange3(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $(".gal3").attr("scrollWidth") - $(".gal3").width();
  $(".gal3").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);
}

function handleSliderSlide3(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $(".gal3").attr("scrollWidth") - $(".gal3").width();
  $(".gal3").attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
}
```

While this works just fine too, I have about 7 of these slides (only 3 are shown above) and I feel kinda bad about repeating basically the same code...

could there be a way to simplify this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that slider demo is quite old and the slider is one of the jQuery UI widgets. It looks like the [side-scroll jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll) demo most closely matches the demo page linked in your question.

I had a play around to see if I could mimic the old demo page in the jQuery UI and came up with **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88tTg/)**. Not sure if it's what you are after though.

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for. Though in this case the slider has to be before the sliding content... since I can deal with it with css, it's no problem :D

Thanks much! :D

Comment: If you need the slider and content to be ordered differently you could just change the `sibling` that jQuery is looking for. Maybe using [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) rather than next() if the slider and content are siblings.

Answer (score 1):

You could include it in a function and pass all the necessary variables:

```
function divSlider(Handle, divId) {

  this.slider({
    animate: true,
    handle: Handle,
    change: handleSliderChange(e, ui, divId);
    slide: handleSliderSlide(e, ui, divId)  });

function handleSliderChange(e, ui, divId)
{
  var maxScroll = divId.attr("scrollWidth") - divId.width();
  divId.animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);
}

function handleSliderSlide(e, ui, divId)
{
  var maxScroll = divId.attr("scrollWidth") - divId.width();
  divId.attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
}

}
```

then you could call it by

```
$('slider1').divSlider('.handle1', $('.gal1'));
```

Im not a 100% sure if this works.. but I guess it will put you in the right direction

Comment: hmm, just tried it out and somehow it doesn't seem to work.. dunno why

Comment: Humm I haven't used it a whole lot either, try reading here:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/basil/archive/2008/09/22/defining-your-own-functions-in-jquery.aspx

and try leaving the handleslider functions outside of the divslider function too